# C# 2.0 Empty Collection

Tags: collections, null, c#-2.0, empty-list

I'm working on a library written in .NET 2.0 that has a static method which returns an object of type list.

During unit testing I ran into a sneaky little bug whereby an exception was being thrown on a line that had nothing to do with the error. Eventually I discovered it was the result of this list returning null.

To prevent this type of situation, I see that the [recommended way to return](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/2596334) this type of collection is to use [`Enumerable.Empty<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). However, that requires Linq (.NET 3.5 +).

#### Is there a better way (best practice?) to return a collection other than null in this situation?

- Is there an `Enumerable.Empty<T>()` .NET 2 (non-Linq) equivalent?

---

Here is my attempt to use @EagleBeak's suggestion:

```c#
namespace MethodReturnEmptyCollection
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static List<ExampleItem> MyCustomList = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyCustomList = CreateEmptyListOfExampleItems();
        }

        private static List<ExampleItem> CreateEmptyListOfExampleItems()
        {
            // Throws an invalid cast exception...
            return (List<ExampleItem>)GetEmptyEnumerable<List<ExampleItem>>(); 
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> GetEmptyEnumerable<T>()
        {
            return new T[0];
        }
    }

    public class ExampleItem
    {
        // item properties... 
    }
}
```

When executed, the following exception is generated:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>     MethodReturnEmptyCollection.exe
>
> {"Unable to cast object of type
>     'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MethodReturnEmptyCollection.ExampleItem][]' to type
>     'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[MethodReturnEmptyCollection.ExampleItem]'."}

---

### Update:

After EagleBeak's input, I found this question which answers mine and is quite interesting:
[Is it better to use Enumerable.Empty() as opposed to new List to initialize an IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894038/2596334)

Found this too:
[According to Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714395/2596334), you can also use `yield break` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throw away the two private methods and initialize your list in the constructor like this:

`MyCustomList = new List<ExampleItem>()`;

PS: `Enumerable.Empty<T>` wouldn't work for you anyway. `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, not the other way round.

Comment: Could you please post some code? The methood I posted works in .Net 2.0.

Comment: Oh, now I see, the solution should be much simpler even. I didn't know that you had a private field of type List<ExampleItem>. You can't cast an array to a List.

Comment: Wow, it was so obvious I didn't even consider it. What then, is the purpose of `Enumerable.Empty<TResult>`? It seems like all it's good for is improving readability and making things more generic.

Comment: Enumerable.Empty<TResult> would actually work if your field were of type IEnumerable. Because your field is of type List<T> you can only assign instances of classes which inherit from List<T>.